# Copying Rectangles Automatically in Qml

Tags: qml

Is it possible to make a certain amount of copies of a rectangle maybe by using a for loop or by any other way with the ability of changing each rectangle attributes like x,y,width etc.. by using `QML`

I have tried the following :

```
var x = 0
var t = 80
var z = 125
var Rectangle = []
if(rs.rows.length > 0){
  x = 2
  for(var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++){
    Rectangle[i] = rectangle18
    Rectangle[i].x = t
    Rectangle[i].y = z
    Rectangle[i].visible = true

    t = t - 40
    z = z - 7
  }
}
```

But unfortunately it's not working with me, is there a way of making this working

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite that simple.  You need to use [Qt.createComponent and that object's createObject() call](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html) to achieve what you want.  It's not just a matter of creating the rectangle and then copying it, you need to load each new copy separately from a qml file.

Something like:

```
var rects = []
var creator = Qt.createComponent("myRect.qml")
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rects[i] = creator.createObject(PARENT)
    rects[i].x = ...
}
```

Obviously extrapolating it to what you need.  Note the reference to PARENT, which is the object that should end up containing the rectangle, which is often a container like a Grid or something.

Comment: Wow u made it looks complicated to me :). is it possible to copy a rectangle using something like property varient rects = []

Comment: No, it's not.  The above way is doing very special things internally, like creating a new C++ object underneath to house the qml object.  You can't just clone a reference, unfortunately, that I know of.  I was surprised too when I first ran into this.  However, you get used to it quickly.  It's just as easy as you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the `Qt.CreateComponent` method you can also consider using a [Repeater](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-repeater.html) component with a `ListModel` containing the info for each `Rectangle`. Here is an example placing 4 `Rectangle` in the scene:

```
ListModel {
  id: modelRects
  ListElement { _x: 0;   _y:0 ;   _width: 10; _height: 10; _color: "red" }
  ListElement { _x: 100; _y:0 ;   _width: 20; _height: 20; _color: "blue" }
  ListElement { _x: 0;   _y:100 ; _width: 30; _height: 30; _color: "yellow" }
  ListElement { _x: 100; _y:100 ; _width: 40; _height: 40; _color: "green" }
}

Repeater {
  model: modelRects
  delegate: Rectangle {
    width: _width
    height: _height
    x: _x
    y: _y
    color: _color
  }
}
```

If you don't want to create the `ListModel` you can also base your calculations on the `index` of the element. Here is an example growing the `Rectangle` based on the index:

```
Repeater {
  model: 5
  delegate: Rectangle {
    // Index starts at 0 so you want a width higher than 0 on first element
    width: 10 * (index + 1)
    height: 10 * (index + 1)
    x: 50 * index
    y: 50 * index
    color: "red"
  }
}
```